# Laradock Redis Exception READONLY You can't write against a read only replica

Tags: laravel, redis, laradock

I am using Laradock to deploy a Laravel application.

Suddenly I get the following error, when hitting the welcome page of the app:

> RedisException READONLY You can't write against a read only replica

I have set to true the installation of Redis in the three workspace, php-fpm, and worker containers:

*.env*

```
WORKSPACE_INSTALL_PHPREDIS=true
PHP_FPM_INSTALL_PHPREDIS=true
PHP_WORKER_INSTALL_REDIS=true
```

I also get the exact same error if I test redis in *Artisan tinker*

```sh
➜  www git:(master) ✗ artisan tinker    
Psy Shell v0.11.4 (PHP 8.1.5 — cli) by Justin Hileman
>>> \Cache::store('redis')->put('Laradock', 'Awesome', 10);
RedisException with message 'READONLY You can't write against a read only replica.'
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: did you find any clues for this?

Comment: Yeah, I fixed it ... as far as I remember, I had to rebuild or restart the containers :P ...

Comment: I've rebuild the container(s) many times but the problem is still occurring. It helps to restart the container, but the problem occur again in less then 24 hours. Did someone found fix to this problem?

Answer (score 2):

I had restart docker container (redis) to fix it

Comment: Restart the container only fix it for a short time. This error will come up again. I still have no idea what is wrong with the container.

Answer (score 2):

add this to your redis docker compose

```
​command: redis-server --appendonly yes --replica-read-only no ​
```

using `redis-cli` check if `config get replica-read-only​` gives value `no`.

Sorce:
https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/servers/docker-on-production-error-redisexception-readonly-you-cant-write-against-a-read-only-replica

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for k8s Redis installation so in redis-config.yaml change this line from yes to no

replica-read-only yes >> replica-read-only no